# Does the pawn's initial double square move have a special name?

Tags: pawns, terminology

Does the pawn's initial double square move have a special name, akin to how special capturing move that the pawn has is called en passant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's a standard move. By definition, pawns are pieces which can move 1 square forward or 2 on the first move, and can capture diagonally. These actions don't have special names as they're easy to define, but en passant requires a bit more explanation (as most pawns never do it in any particular game).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!